# How to document JavaScript/CoffeeScript data structures

Tags: javascript, documentation, coffeescript

I am looking for a descriptive way to document the used data structures in my JavaScript application. I find it hard to get this done due to the dynamic character of JavaScript.

For instance, what could be a good way to tell, that a used variable **distance** is a two-dimensional array with length i and j and stores numbers between **-1** and **MAX_INT**. I could think of something like this:

```
distance[i][j] = -1 <= n <= MAX_INT
```

What about an object which is used as a **map/dictionary** for certain data types, what about a two-dimensional array where the first element of an array defines other data then the rest, etc.

Of course, it is always possible to document these things in a text, I just thought, maybe there is a well known and used way to do this in a semiformal way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it's not too widely adopted (yet?), there is a [draft standard for JSON schema](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-zyp-json-schema-03). I'm just learning it myself but you could write a schema for your two-dimensional array (wrapped inside of an object) as:

```
{
    "description":"Two dimensional array of numbers",
    "type":"object",
    "properties":{
        "two-d-array":{
            "description":"columns",
            "type":"array",
            "items":{
                "description":"rows",
                "type":"array",
                "items": {
                   "description":"values",
                   "type":"number",
                   "minimum":-1,
                   "maximum":Number.MAX_VALUE
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

or simply:

```
{
    "type":"array",
    "items":{
        "type":"array",
        "items": {
            "type":"number",
            "minimum":-1,
            "maximum":Number.MAX_VALUE
        }
    }
}
```

There is no CoffeeScript implementation that I know of, but there is a list of several JavaScript validators [here](http://json-schema.org/implementations.html). I'm playing with the one that's written by the spec authors called (simply enough) [json-schema](https://github.com/kriszyp/json-schema) and I like it well enough calling it from CoffeeScript.

Comment: Note: Number.MAX_VALUE is not supported by json-schema. You'll need to expand that for your purposes. I tend to try to limit my true "INTs" to 2^32-1, because the bitwise operators only work on numbers this large, but technically in JavaScript any number whose mantissa fits in 2^53 is considered valid.

Answer (score 1):

What I tend to do in my JavaScript when I am replicating a lot of data models is to write out what their class definition would be in comments.  I am not sure if this is what you meant with your question.

```
// JavaScript Class jsHomeLocation
// jsHomeLocation{
// string name
// string address
// }

var jsHomeLocation = {};
jsHomeLocation.name = "Travis";
jsHomeLocation.address = "California";
```

You could also use javascript objects to track the information of the example, a two-dimensional array

```
var distanceData = {};
distanceData.type = "two-dimensional array";
distanceData.length = i * j;
distanceData.min = -1;
distanceData.max = MAX_INT;
```